# Raty Js Star Rating to give Float Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app Admin can enter a rating for each user. Im using raty js to show and also to input the star rating..

Thing is I can get an integer value through this. IM trying to set float values through this like half star and all
This is what i did.. But still the output is all fullstars.. not half stars..

```
$('#expert_star').raty({
                <% expert_score = (@expert_rating && @expert_rating.score.present?) ? @expert_rating.score : 0 %>
                showHalf:  true,
                score: <%= expert_score %>,
                readOnly: <%= expert_score > 0 ? true : false %>,
                mouseover: function(score) {
                    console.log("Score: "+score);
                }
            });
```

Ignore the ruby codes in side jquery script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add half: true and try.